# How to refer a table column as clause condition with Arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have this scope:

```
scope :in_range, lambda { |begin_time, end_time, excluded_sales = nil|
  where(
    'start_at BETWEEN ? AND ? OR finish_at BETWEEN ? AND ? OR ? BETWEEN start_at AND finish_at OR ? BETWEEN start_at AND finish_at',
  begin_time, end_time, begin_time, end_time, begin_time, end_time)
  .where.not(id: excluded_sales)
}
```

This produces

```
> Sale.in_range(Time.now, Time.now + 1)
  Sale Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "sales".* FROM "sales"  WHERE (start_at BETWEEN '2014-12-12 10:45:47.065712' AND '2014-12-12 10:45:48.065714' OR finish_at BETWEEN '2014-12-12 10:45:47.065712' AND '2014-12-12 10:45:48.065714' OR '2014-12-12 10:45:47.065712' BETWEEN start_at AND finish_at OR '2014-12-12 10:45:48.065714' BETWEEN start_at AND finish_at) AND ("sales"."id" IS NOT NULL)
```

I need to rewrite this scope using Arel because I believe I should not use raw SQL syntax here.
But I do not know how to use `in` method with table column reference. I've tried this but got exception:

```
> s = Sale.arel_table
> begin_time = Time.now
> Sale.where(begin_time.in(s[:start_at]..s[:finish_at]))
  --> ArgumentError: bad value for range
```

Also tried this, but had no luck:

```
> s = Sale.arel_table
> begin_time = Time.now
> Sale.where(begin_time.in('sales.start_time'..'sales.end_time')
  --> NoMethodError: undefined method `round' for "sales.end_time".."sales.start_time":Range
```

Please advise how to refer a table column as clause condition with Arel?

Thank you!

**UPDATED:**

There are four conditions connected with `OR` statement:

1. `start_at` in range of `begin_time` and `end_time`
2. `finish_at` in range of `begin_time` and `end_time`
3. `begin_time` in range of `start_time` and `finish_time`
4. `end_time` in range of `start_time` and `finish_time`

Basically it is just a date ranges overlap.

I rewrote it to

```
scope :in_range, lambda { |date_range, excluded_sales = nil|
  s = Sale.arel_table
  where(
    s.grouping(s[:starts_at].gteq(date_range.first).and(s[:starts_at].lteq(date_range.last)))
      .or(s.grouping(s[:ends_at].gteq(date_range.first).and(s[:ends_at].lteq(date_range.last))))
      .or(s.grouping(s[:starts_at].lteq(date_range.first).and(s[:ends_at].gteq(date_range.last))))
      .or(s.grouping(s[:starts_at].gteq(date_range.first).and(s[:ends_at].lteq(date_range.last))))
  ).where.not(id: excluded_sales)
}
```

Maybe there is a simplier way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well as far as I understood, you wish to select all record, which range have an intersection to the specified one? If so, just select records, which have `start_at` field values that are before the end of range, and have `finish_at` field values that are after the begin of range. So with [arel](/questions/tagged/arel) it should be:

```
 scope :in_range, proc do |begin_time, end_time, excluded_sales|
    where(arel_table[:start_at].lteq(end_time)
     .and(arel_table[:finish_at].gteq(begin_time))
     .and(arel_table[:id].not_eq(excluded_sales)))
 end
```

Comment: Please take a look to my update question - I have added possible solution and conditions for this query. Maybe you can review it? Thanks!

Comment: @TimurKhafizov на самом деле ваш вариант правильный, но моего достаточно, и он проще, я когда то вычислял как правильно и оптимально считать пересечение диапазонов.

Comment: Yep, all my tests pass, so it seems to be the best solution. Thank you!